# get_the_content not working in loop?

Tags: loop, the-content, debug

I am trying to modify my loop to save post data by category. I found some code on this site that saved the post's titles based on their categories and tried to modify this to save the post's content. However, while `get_the_title` and `get_the_category` work, `get_the_content` returns null.

Here is the code:

```
if ( false === ( $q = get_transient( 'category_list' ) ) ) {

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args); 

    $q = array();

    $body = array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

        $query->the_post(); 

        $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        $post_id = $post->ID;

        $body[$post_id] = array();

        $body[$post_id]['title'] = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>'; //works

        $body[$post_id]['content'] = get_the_content('Read more');

        $categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

            $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';

        }

        $q[$b][] = $post_id; // Create an array with the category names and post titles

    }


    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

    set_transient( 'category_list', $q, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
  }
```

Edit: Here is how I am using the `$body` array:

```
foreach($q[$b] as $post) {
  echo('<div class="teaser"><div class="teaser-title"><a href = "">' . $post . '</a></div><div class="teaser-text">'. $body[$post] . '</div><div class="teaser-footer"><p>pemsource.org</p></div></div>');
}
```

Edit2: I added the full code. When I do a var dump of body I get NULL and when I do a var dump of $q I get

```
array(3) { ["Conundrums"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(64) "new post" } ["Tips and Tricks"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(80) "Tips and tricks" } ["Uncategorized"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(78) "Tips and Tricks" } }
```

seemingly regardless of how I edit the loop. I am very confused. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Does that post have content? And your saving the $content to the array $body, but where are you using $body?

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: try `global $post; $content = $post->post_content;`

Comment: where you put your loop?

Comment: @Jevuska: It's in index.php

Comment: whoops I mean: `global $post; $content = apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);`

Comment: if you use `get_the_content`, you should check a filter into the_content,  and other loop in the same page may cause your issue.

Comment: You are storing everything in a transient. Once the transient is set, any changes made inside the code will not work and only show when the transient expire. If you need to make changes, make sure to flush the transient first. I always test code without the transient, it is much less headaches than to flush the transient on every change

Comment: @PieterGoosen: That worked, but I am not sure if I need the transient? I read the documentation but am still not sure what the transient does. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the code in your question is not mine, if so, which answer did you get it from. I remember explaining the huge performance gain you get from the transient ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`echo $post->post_content;` will echo your post content. Keep in mind though, it's raw out of the database (same as `get_the_content()`). If you want to apply the same filters that `the_content()` receives, follow the instructions in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/#Alternative_Usage):

```
<?php
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
?>
```

Comment: how about the text link 'Read more'?

Comment: For Read More link <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read more &raquo; <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>

Answer (score -1):

maybe try `<?php` instead of `<?` in your lines of code, not sure but I understand that this can cause problems.

or use `<?php echo $post->post_content; ?>`
and try without 'Read More' means only  `<?php the_content(); ?>`