# Load Posts' individual body content on index starting at char 200 of each post

Tags: filters, the-content

I would like to have my index or [posts overview page](https://publiqly.com/blog/) load each post teaser starting at char 206 of each post's body content. This as all posts start with a general introduction in the post body content that is the same. To load that on the index.php teaser is useless information.

With `get_the_post` I managed to load content but the `substr` does not work as it should. It filter the content for the page. Not for the content of each page (body text).

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

/*
Template name: Blog Page
*/

get_header();
the_post();

?>

<div class="grid-container blog" id="main-container">

    <div class="grid-100 mobile-grid-100 nopadding" id="normal-content-wrap">

        <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>

        <?php 
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        //$content = strip_tags($content);
        echo substr($content, 200, 20);
        echo $content;
        //the_content();?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see I commented out the `strip_tags` as I realized the formatting is fine. I do not want to loose the formatting. I just want each individual post to show a piece of that post starting at char x. How can this be done?

Comment: Checking https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224817/get-the-content-not-working-in-loop for get_the_content and loop issues now too.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine

```
 if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
      the_post();
      $content = get_the_content();
      echo substr($content, 200, 20);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well I tried that before and that loads nothing. The variable `$content` also shows length zero doing a `var_dump`

Comment: are you using the WP loop?

Comment: No, see the code. It loaded `the_content` just fine without a loop there before. And that way it loads all post teasers. Using `apply_filter` it does allow me to use `get_the_content`, but it won't do. Please do share the complete code you would suggest then. Did try a loop before, but in vain..

Comment: get_the_content() works inside the loop only. Check edited answer

Comment: Yeah, and tried your code example before once, myself, but zero content is loaded this way I'm afraid.

Comment: Works good for me on twentyseventeen theme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66186/discussion-between-piyush-rawat-and-rhand).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it without standard loop, just using global variables

```
global $post;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Comment: Well doing a `$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); echo $content;` does get me to load the same and have the excerpt replace post content where an excerpt has been added so this seems to be a great option. However also just using `the_content` does the same too I realized. My initial approach was loading the `post_content` starting at char 204 and then a teaser. Perhaps I will stick to an excerpt there and be done with it.